# UIButton not getting the action within the swift code

Tags: swift

[image]

Is there a reason why this action wont work within the code? Im dumb founded.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the outlet completely and reattaching the button to .swift file using the ^control key in Editor>Assistant mode.

Comment: i took them out of the ui view and they worked.... weird